# Updating react state in parent very slow

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-state

I'm developing a react application, and where I always thought the react state updates were really fast, I now found a problem.

I have a page view with a lot of elements on it, one of the elements is this one that gets loaded in the page:

```
<NotesCard notes={deal.notes} updateNotes={notes => {setDeal(prevState => ({...prevState, notes}))}} />
```

NotesCard is a child component that only renders a material-ui Card with another react component in:

```
export default function NotesCard(props) {
    const {notes, updateNotes} = props;
    return (
        <Card className="Card">
            <CardHeader
                title="Notities"
            />
            <CardContent>
                <Notes notes={notes} onChange={updateNotes} />
            </CardContent>
        </Card>
    );
}
```

Notes is the last component that renders a text field and just takes the props to the TextField:

```
function Notes(props) {
    const {notes} = props;

    function updateNotes(event) {
        // props.deal.notes = event.target.value;
        props.onChange(event.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <FormGroup>
                {notes !== null ?
                    <TextField
                        multiline
                        defaultValue={notes}
                        onChange={e => updateNotes(e)}
                        rows={3}
                        variant={'outlined'}
                        label={'Notities'}
                    />
                    : 'Geen beschrijving...'}
            </FormGroup>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Is there anything that I do wrong that creates a lot of lag? The page is a big page so it might have something to do with that, but I'd think that the updates performances would still be okay.

Comment: Your `updateNotes` prop is an anonymous callback, recreated each time `NotesCard` is rendered. You may try declaring it *before* the render return, or memoize it with `useCallback` hook if you are doing this same callback logic in multiple rendered components. Can you show more of the component that is rendering `NotesCard`? The state, etc... of that parent component?

Comment: @DrewReese I only use it once on the page so it shouldn't be a very big deal. I tried changing it but it didn't really improve.

Comment: Use what once per page? Changed what? I have a suspicion you are mapping a bunch of notes/notecards/etc... somewhere and they are all trying to update the same state. I don't think the where the notes are rendered is where a "bottleneck" is occurring. Can you provide a more comprehensive code example so we can see what the app is doing with (presumably) a bunch of notes and updates?

Comment: I only have the Notes once, so not a bunch of them. On further investigation it seems like a problem with firestore that we use, that sends 4 network calls with every rerender after typing a letter...

Comment: Oh, yeah, that could degrade performance. Have you tried debouncing that call to your firestore upon update of the input value?

Comment: I tracked it down and it seems the problem comes from a completely other component that's using the main object from the parent. That component renders a dialog that does those calls every time it gets created. And for some reason that dialog gets created every time a key was pressed...

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is to fix the slow render, only then you will want to take a look at number of rerenders if necessary.
Please install the react-dev-tools which contains an option to mark components when the are being rerendered. Alternativly you can also monitor the performance over a couple of seconds and investigate the rendering. This should help you understand what renders unnecessarily on your actions.

I see a potential problem with this one:

```
<Notes notes={notes} onChange={updateNotes} />
```

If you trigger onChange the parent state is mutated. This then causes ALL children to rerender. I would think that only the single  will change and a change in this component wont effect other siblings. So try to move the state as close to where its used as possible. If you trigger onChange only the  should be updated. This is something easy which can fix a ton of performance problems without using react features like Memo.

Comment: What if the parent component needs to store those `notes`? It seems unavoidable in many cases to have the state stored in the parent.

Comment: There is always a better architecture. Here for example your problem is that each keystroke is changing the top-most parent. There are multiple solutions:
- keep the state close to where its needed (initialize useState with your deal.notes and then only manipulate the state). Gather the local state once its needed (e.g. submit form)
- use uncontrolled form controls. The thing you mention is a common problem with react forms. https://react-hook-form.com/ was able to solve it for me on one problem. A form control is just setting itself, no need for upper state.